# Referencing unnumbered theorems

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, amsthm

I would like to reference named (but unnumbered theorems) with a hyperlink. I have a solution which I consider at least a semi-hack:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem*{Zorn}{Zorn's lemma}

\begin{document}
\begin{Zorn}
\hypertarget{lem:Zorn}{}
This is Zorn's lemma
\end{Zorn}

That was \hyperlink{lem:Zorn}{Zorn's lemma}.
\end{document}
```

However I wonder if there is a neater solution (possibly using `thmtools` or `cleveref`) that would reference back to a `\label` for the unnumbered theorem?

Comment: I don't think this is a hack. However, you could use `\newtheorem*{lemma}{Lemma}` and then `\begin{lemma}[Zorn]\label{lem:zorn}...\end{lemma}` with `\nameref{lem:zorn}`. It would change the display of the lemma's though (with the name in brackets.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a fake counter to keep `hyperref` happy:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsthm,lipsum}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem*{namedthm}{\namedthmname}
\newcounter{namedthm}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{named}[1]
  {\def\namedthmname{#1}%
   \refstepcounter{namedthm}%
   \namedthm\def\@currentlabel{#1}}
  {\endnamedthm}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{named}{Zorn's lemma}\label{lem:Zorn}
This is Zorn's lemma
\end{named}

\lipsum[1-6]

That was \ref{lem:Zorn}.

\end{document}
```

You can have as many unnumbered theorems as you want.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks. However... when I insert it to the long book I am writing I get two "undefined control sequence" errors pointing to the line containing the `\newcounter`. Quite possibly this is related to me using `thmtools` and `cleveref`?

Comment: @Noam That's a possibility; try with `\newtheorem*{namedthm}{\protect\namedthmname}`

Comment: This does not work with \cref (from cleveref), only with \ref. Is there an easy way to address that?

Comment: @McDuffin What should `\cref` do?

Comment: That's a very good question! I guess \ref here does exactly what I want (I'm just used to using \cref as a sort of best practice). I retract my question